# Started Spring 2.5 Project-- how to create global connection pool using c3p0

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I have started a project using spring ..i know the standards to be followed in a real time project ..

But i am unable to get how to use the c3p0 connection pool in my project..

I have configured in .xml file but every time if i need the connection object i am loading the xml and using useBean() method to get the connection object . i know it is not good to load xml every time and get bean..instead i want that connection pool to be placed in context and connection to be created only once and placed in context for availability to all the classes i need.

Please can any one help me..Where i have to place the DB configuration..

Should i use Spring MVC dispatcher-servlet.xml and inject the connection reference into all the classes where i need the connection object ??

Please assist me..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is unclear what you are asking for, please rephrase your question.

Comment: If you're starting a project, why do you start it with a Spring version that is 7 years old. Spring is at version 4.0. You shouldn't use 2.5: it's obsolete.

Comment: Maybe you'll consider using SpringBoot - http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/ It has a lot of benefits over standard Spring - like autoconfiguration

Comment: Let me be more specific..i am using Spring MVC and i am confused of how to configured the connection pool..And you recommended me to use Spring 3..If suppose i use Spring MVC 2.5 shall i have to inject the datasource object into jdbctemplate for each and every class for which i need connection object  ??
And if i use Spring MVC 3 and the annotation @Autowired takes care of injecting the datasource object into all the related classes so there is no need of developer to inject to each and every class as Spring container takes care of it..